# Plane perpendicular to $r \ \{ \frac{x-1}{2} = y - 2 = \frac{z+1}{4}$ that contains $P = (-1,3,-1)$ - possible textbook mistake

Tags: analytic-geometry

I've been working on a problem on a textbook that asks for the following:

> Find the plane perpendicular to $r \ \{ \frac{x-1}{2} = y - 2 = \frac{z+1}{4}$
>   that contains $P = (-1,3,-1)$

The options are

> a) $4x+z-13 = 0$
>
> b) $2x+y+4z-3 = 0$
>
> c) $4y-z-13=0$
>
> d) $2x+y+4z+13=0$

To me none of the above is correct. After using the vector from the line and placing the point to find the constant of the plane, I've found

> $$ x+2z+3 = 0 $$

Is my answer correct? Or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-2}{1}=\frac{z+1}{4}$$
the normal vector is
$$n=2i+1j+4k$$

the equation of plane is
$$v_x(x-x_0)+v_y(y-y_0)+v_z(z-z_0)=0$$
$$2(x+1)+1(y-3)+4(z+1)=0$$
$$2x+y+4z+3=0$$

Comment: ah I see my mistake, thank you.

Comment: @bru1987 you r welcome